# Unable to find error in C++ code to swap two integer variables

Tags: c++, function

I am currently practising some questions on Functions in C++ and came across this question:-

**Write a program with a function to swap the values of 2 given integer variables.**

I wrote the following code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 void swap(int n1, int n2){
     int org_n1=n1; //fixing original value of n1 before changing 
     n1=n2;
     n2=org_n1;     
     return;          
 }

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    cin>>num1>>num2;
    cout<<"The original value of num1 is: "<<num1<<endl;
    cout<<"The original value of num2 is: "<<num2<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    swap(num1, num2);
    cout<<"The new value of num1 is: "<<num1<<endl;
    cout<<"The new value of num2 is: "<<num2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code is supposed to print the new values of num1 and num2 interchanged, however, it keeps printing their original values.
What's the error here?

Comment: `void swap(int n1, int n2){` => `void swap(int& n1, int& n2){`

Comment: `swap(num1, num2);` => `std::swap(num1, num2);`

Comment: Alternative: throw out your `swap` entirely and just use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) from `<utility>`

Answer (score 0):

Your are only Swapping the Variables inside the Function. The Function only gets copys of the Variable.

```
void swap(int& n1, int& n2){
```

This codes gets the original variables and not the copys.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing by values so the copy integers are swapped in the function but does not change the real number.
you can use
`void swap(int &n1, int &n2)`

or you should pass by reference using pointer.

Comment: Pointers are passed by value. Languages like C don't support real pass by reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference. Why would you simulate pass by reference with pointers in C++?

Comment: @ThomasSablik yeah, using C pointers simulates pass by reference in pass by value strategy .

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass by reference so that the changes made in the function is reflected in the original variables
Use this `void swap(int &n1, int &n2)` instead of `void swap(int n1, int n2)`